Can the Philips Hue Bridge be shutdown without removing the power cable?
The official application appears to not provide power controls, and all of the 3rd-party applications that I've tested solely provide a way to reboot it at best. ^iConnectHue ^HueEssentials
I ask because when I move the device, I want to cleanly disable it, rather than potentially interrupt an action by removing its power source (because, obviously, this provides no opportunity for the device to prepare to be disabled).

what exactly do you mean by shutdown?

@jsotola, I don't know of any definition except deinitialization of the device, so that's what I refer to. More specifically, what systemctl poweroff, shutdown, or Stop-Computer do on their respective desktop OSes.

I am asking what you mean ... in other words, what do you expect the device to do when you issue the shutdown command?

I would expect the device to be designed so that it does not require a power off sequence

https://forum.archive.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=66346

@jsotola, Teltonika claims the same, but that's merely an assertion of the seller, rather than a technical solution. It indeed probably has mitigating measures to cope with random shutdowns, but I do not intend to rely upon those.

@jsotola, I have specified what I mean in that same sentence. I mean the sole definition that I know of. I am doubtful that the word could mean multiple things at the high level we're using it.

maybe removing the network connection before poweroff might be enough

@jsotola, that's not a bad idea. I'm using Ethernet, so that's trivial, too.

Usually only devices with slow (e.g. spinning disks) persistent storage and lots of state in RAM need to be told to "shutdown" before being powered off, this is so they can ensure that any persistent state is flushed to disk. Consumer IoT devices tend to use flash storage and not actually hold state which needs to be saved. So there is no need to do anything before removing the power. E.g. the only state this device needs is the list of paired bulbs, so unless you are in the middle of pairing a new bulb there is nothing to fail to store properly.
